Proof of a couple properties of maximally consistent sets of sentences
This is from p.10 of Chang and Keisler's Model Theory.

Lemma 1.2.10. Suppose $\Gamma$ is a maximally consistent set of sentences. Then: (i) for each sentence $\varphi$, exactly one of $\varphi$, $\neg\varphi \in \Gamma$ and (ii) for each pair of sentences $\varphi$ and $\psi$, $\varphi \land\psi \in\Gamma\iff\varphi\in\Gamma$ and $\psi\in\Gamma$.

I'm wondering whether the following proofs are correct or not. I'm dubious about the first part because of the "...$\Gamma \vdash \neg\varphi \lor \varphi$. Then, $\Gamma \vdash \neg\varphi$ or $\Gamma \vdash \varphi$..." part. I'm dubious about the second part because it doesn't seem to use the fact that $\Gamma$ is maximally consistent.
Proof 1. Let $\Gamma$ be as such. So, $\Gamma$ is consistent, and the only consistent set of sentences which includes $\Gamma$ is $\Gamma$ itself. Since $\Gamma$ is consistent, it is not inconsistent. It follows that $\Gamma \not\vdash \varphi \land \neg\varphi$ for any sentence $\varphi$. Hence, $\Gamma \vdash \neg(\varphi \land \neg\varphi)$, and so $\Gamma \vdash \neg\varphi \lor \varphi$. Then, $\Gamma \vdash \neg\varphi$ or $\Gamma \vdash \varphi$ for any sentence $\varphi$. By part (ii) of Proposition 1.2.8, we have that $\neg\varphi \in \Gamma$ or $\varphi \in \Gamma$ for any sentence $\varphi$.
Now, by the defintion of $\vDash$, we have that $\varphi \land \psi \in \Gamma \iff \Gamma \vDash \phi \land \psi \iff \Gamma \vDash \varphi$ and $\Gamma \vDash \psi \iff \varphi \in \Gamma$ and $\psi \in \Gamma$.
Q.E.D.
This alternate proof doesn't seem quite right either. The proof of (ii) is the same.
Alternate Proof 2. Suppose to the contrary that both $\varphi$ and $\neg\varphi$ belong to $\Gamma$. Then, $\Gamma$ is inconsistent, a contradiction.
Now, suppose that neither $\varphi$ nor $\neg\varphi$ belongs to $\Gamma$. Then, $\Gamma \cup ${$\varphi$} must be inconsistent because $\Gamma$ is maximally consistent. However, $\Gamma \cup ${$\varphi$} must be consistent because $\Gamma$ is consistent and $\neg\varphi \not\in \Gamma$, a contradiction. A similar a argument follows for $\Gamma \cup ${$\neg\varphi$}.
For part (ii), by the defintion of $\vDash$, we have that $\varphi \land \psi \in \Gamma \iff \Gamma \vDash \phi \land \psi \iff \Gamma \vDash \varphi$ and $\Gamma \vDash \psi \iff \varphi \in \Gamma$ and $\psi \in \Gamma$. Q.E.D.
If neither of these proofs is correct, could someone point me in the right direction?

Concerning the first part, what is the definition of maximal consistency? Concerning the second part, what is the definition of $\models$? It is not clear why $\Gamma \models \phi \land \psi$ should imply $\phi \land \psi \in \Gamma$.

Your proofs look correct to me in (ii), and your Proof 2 looks alright for (i), but it seems like you are just missing some connective tissue. Take for instance your Proof 2. The fact that $\Gamma\cup \{\phi\}$ is inconsistent means that $\Gamma\cup\{\phi\}\vdash \bot$. By Proposition 1.2.8 (iv), we have that $\Gamma\vdash \phi\rightarrow \bot$, equivalently, $\Gamma\vdash \neg\phi$. Thus by Proposition 1.2.8 (ii), $\neg\phi\in \Gamma$.
This shows (i) from Lemma 1.2.10. Note that this is essentially your Proof 2, making more explicit use of the Lemmas given by Chang and Keisler (and some propositional logic trickery). I think your Proof 1 uses the fact that whenever $\Gamma\vdash \phi\vee \psi$, then $\Gamma\vdash \phi$ or $\Gamma\vdash \psi$, which is equivalent to the property you are trying to prove!
